# git svn clone -> Conversion of huge repository crashes all the time - is there a remedy?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, svn, git-svn

In the last couple of days I've been unsuccessfully trying to clone our huge SVN repository to GIT.

All the time, sooner or later, I'm running into the following error:

```
Software caused connection to abort: Error running context: Software caused connection abort at: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Ra.pn line 312.
```

[image: Timeout error]

I couldn't find any log entry on my Windows 10 client nor on the Ubuntu server giving details on the reason for this error.

[StackOverflow question #53157918](/questions/53157918/git-svn-fetch-error-running-context-software-caused-connection-abort-at) suggested to increase the Apache server timeout value. I increased the Apache timeout value to 10 times the original timeout value - but, apparently, this didn't help.

Following the StdOut output, reading each of the files is a snap, so I don't suggest it's a transmission timeout issue, anyway.

## Edit

I just tried again ... This time the error is Out of Memory:

```
libsvn: Out of memory - terminating application.
      1 [main] perl 735 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to perl.exe.stackdump
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Already tried Git-2.29.2.2-64-bit.exe and it fails with the same issue. I'd expect that it'll be worse, but I'll try Git-2.26.2-64-bit.exe now, followed by 32-bit ones.

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting errors or hangs midway when running `git svn clone`, or when running `git svn fetch` after the first `git svn clone` attempt.

I finally succeeded by giving up on accessing my Subversion repository via an `http` or `https` URL.  Instead, I copied the Subversion repository from my Subversion server (a Windows Server) to the computer where I was running `git svn clone` from (a Linux PC).  I could then specify a local path to the repository in the `git svn clone` command line, e.g.

```
# navigate to a directory containing your authors.txt file
cd /some/directory

# run git svn clone, reading a Subversion repository from a local path
git -c gc.auto=0 -c init.defaultBranch=main svn clone --stdlayout --authors-file=authors.txt file:///some/local/path/MySvnRepo MyLocalGitRepo
```

This not only ran to completion on the first try, processing over 28,000 commits, but also ran in less than 2 hours.

I had previously created a temporary Subversion repository based on an `svnadmin dump` of my primary Subversion repository.  I processed the initial `.dump` file using `svndumpfilter` to exclude files by extension.  The resulting `.dump` file excluded all large binary files such as `.lib`, `.dll`, `.pdf`, etc. The new temporary Subversion repository created from the filtered `.dump` file was only 600 MB rather than several GB.  This helped the `git svn clone` go faster.

Comment: This sounds like a great solution. Unfortunately, the project I've been working on was back years ago. Yet, incidentally, I've been assigned to the same task again for a new client. As soon as I'm going to migrate my new client's repositories, I will check your answer and upvote happily if it does the trick! 

Answer (score 0):

As the workaround you can kick-off Ubuntu virtual machine and import your repository there. Here is what I did.

Download and install [Oracle Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).
Download and use [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download) iso as your OS.

Run terminal and install `git` and `git-svn`

```
sudo apt-get install git git-svn
```

Follow your procedure to checkout. Using this method I've successfully downloaded big SVN repo into `git` and transferred it to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

As you encountered the `out of memory` error, it would be a good idea to increase the git limit and window size and cache, etc. Probably this is the solution:

1. `cd /migrated/git/repo/.git` the directory created after `git svn clone` command
2. edit `.git/config` file as below:

under `[core]` section add lines

```
    packedGitLimit = 512m
    packedGitWindowSize = 512m
    longpaths = true
```

and also add following sections:

```
[http]
    postBuffer = 100000000
[pack]
  deltaCacheSize = 256m
  packSizeLimit = 256m
  windowMemory = 1024m
```